# Why would this print 10 stars?

Tags: c

```
for(i = 0; i<10 ; ++i)
  printf("*");
```

As per my logic, this prompt should print 9 stars, because the ++i is the first operation, making i=1 before it checks the condition. so then from i = 1 all they way to i = 9, it will print *'s which would be 9 *'s. Right?

Comment: I think you need to start with some good tutorials . Here are few
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm , 
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html

Answer (score 7):

It would print 10 stars because you are counting from `0` to `9` .. that is 10 iterations

The first iteration will be with `i=0` not `1`

`++i` is executed once the stuff inside the for loop has been actioned

**Steps of for loop:**

1. Initiate the loop with initiating condition ( `i=0`) And check terminating condition
2. Action the commands inside the loop
3. Action the increment/decrement condition ( `++i` ) - **This isn't executed unless the commands inside the loop have been actioned**
4. Check terminating condition ( `i<9`) - Exit the loop if condition not met
5. Action commands inside loop again
6. Apply increment/decrement again
7. repeat 4-7

**Question:**

**Why was this question by OP downvoted?**

To me this question seems very genuine for someone starting out in programming. Why can't we be more encouraging and helpful rather than demotivating someone for asking genuine questions?

I understand that this question may be too trivial for most of you guys, but that is not a reason to discourage someone from asking such questions ( particularly if they are new to programming )

Comment: but the ++i is the first function, so you would be going from 1-9 because 0 doesnt enter the loop, right?

Comment: @user2918658 that third clause is run at the end of each iteration

Comment: @user2918658 no .. the loop starts with the initial condition .. actions the commands inside the loop and then proceeds to action the increment/decrement condition.

Comment: what do you mean by "first function". The semicolon `;` seperates the statements, so in the for loop there are *3 statements*. The first one is outside the loop. The next one is executed at the begin of each loop. The last one will be run at the loop's end. As the loop hasn't come to end, ++i is yet to be executed.

Comment: @sukhvir: your edited code is wrong. Terminating condition is checked every beginning of the loop. So `s = 0; for (i = 0; i < s; i++) dosomething();` wouldn't ever run.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc You are correct .. see the edit

Comment: Thanks @sukhvir, that actually helped more than anyone else's answer

Comment: @sukhvir I think the downvotes are there because stack overflow should not be used as a begginer's help desk. This is a genuine question but can be answered by almost anyone that has done a bit of programming, or is quickly solved by some simple search (googling "C for loop" for instance) so this has nothing to do on SO.

Comment: @Eregrith fair enough

Answer (score 7):

> As per my logic, this prompt should print 9 stars, because the ++i is the first operation,

And here you are wrong.

```
for (a; b; c) d
```

is equivalent to

```
a;
while (b) {
    d;
    c;
}
```

so `c` is NOT executed at first, but only after the first iteration.

Thus, you have 10 iterations.

Answer (score 3):

If you convert this into equivalent to while loop it would be:

```
i = 0;
while (i<10) {
  printf("*");
  ++i;
}
```

what you are looking for is;

```
i = 0;
while (++i<10) {
  printf("*");
}
```

So the equivalent for loop would be:

```
for (i = 0; ++i < 10;) {
    printf("*");
}
```

Where you increment the variable at the logical check step.

Comment: Your first code block is incorrect. ++i; should come after the printf, not before. (But the core point you're making seems right to me.)

Comment: Sorry my bad fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

> Quote:  because the ++i is the first operation, making i=1 before it checks the condition

That's were you go wrong. ++i is the last operation of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

For loop starts like this 
for(i=0; i<10;++i)

1st here i=0 is evaluated then checks the condition i<10.
then do operation in loop then i will be incremented i.e ++i.then it checks condition i<10;
like this it will continue up to 0 to 9 then stops.

So 1st time i=0 it doesnt matter ++i or i++ since it will evaluated at end of execution statement within loop.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop condition is checked before entering each iteration, and the increment part is evaluated after each iteration. On the first iteration i is 0 and it is incremented after printf; not before. Using ++i or i++ doesn't matter.